# Access Violation - Polymorphic behaviour C++ Builder XE with Delphi IInterface

Tags: c++, delphi, polymorphism, c++builder

Given the following code with details I think are not relevant (but they could be) removed:

```
class __declspec(uuid("{AD72C6C5-E48F-40CA-8F46-98916229144D}")) TMyInterface
    : public IUnknown {

  public:
    virtual void GetValue(String &value) = 0;
};

template <typename T> class TInterfaceable : public T, public TMyInterface {

  public:
    __fastcall TInterfaceable(TComponent *Owner) : T(Owner)
    {
    }

    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const GUID &IID, void **Obj)
    {
        return TComponent::QueryInterface(IID, (void *)Obj);
    }

    ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
    {
        return TComponent::_AddRef();
    }

    ULONG __stdcall Release()
    {
        return TComponent::_Release();
    }
};

class PACKAGE TMyLabel : public TInterfaceable<TLabel> {

  public:
    __fastcall TTuningLabel(TComponent *Owner) : TInterfaceable<TLabel>(Owner)
    {
    }
    virtual void GetValue(String &value)
    {
        value = this->Caption; 
/* I get an access violation here. Read of address FFFFFE6C.
I break here and examine the value of the this pointer.
The this pointer address is very close to the access violation value */
/* Note: If I change the code to `value = "test"` I get a different
AV, this time Write of Address 0x005DC9B0 */

    }
};

int main(void)
{

    for (/*control in list of controls...*/) {
        TControl * control = c;/* im looping thru testing a collection of controls */

        TMyInterface *p = System::interface_cast<TMyInterface>(control);

        if (p != NULL) {
            /* This has been tested to only evaluate not null on the one
             * control that actually implements the interface. */
            String v;
            p->GetValue(v);
            ShowMessage(v);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an access violation (see code comments for location). The this pointer seems to have an incorrect value in the debugger, but this wouldn't explain the access violation when writing to the argument.

I guess I might be violating some polymorphic rules of multiple inheritance or something about the template class?

Thanks

Comment: The debugger won't always show the correct value of `this` if it's been optimised out.  Don't break, but instead print it to the console via cout or something similar. (It may also be useful for us to see the actual value(s) it prints.) Basically, how do you know the value you're seeing is that actual value? Does it crash when you try to access this with an address near 0xffffffff, or does it work fine and is it just that the debugger reports something odd?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your question actually is. You've observed some odd behaviour. But is it causing a crash, or are you asking for an explanation for the debugger's value (one possible explanation is in my comment above) or...?

Comment: Rather than print out a constant, you should print out something that belongs to the object, like its `Caption`, that way you will know for sure whether the `this` pointer is being used correctly or not, even if optimized.

Comment: I have to apologise, I simplified the code from what the initial problem was because I thought the problem was still there due to the this pointer being strange. Normally the debugger tells me if the value has been optimised out. I will update the question with a more specific question and the actual code causing the issue. Thanks

Comment: I tried this in C++Builder XE and cannot reproduce it. I tried in both a VCL Forms and a Console application. Please provide a complete project, or at least complete source code.